# Get the sum of all digits in a numeric string

Tags: php, string, sum

How do I find the sum of all the digits in a number in PHP?

Answer (score 119):

```
array_sum(str_split($number));
```

This assumes the number is positive (or, more accurately, that the conversion of `$number` into a string generates only digits).

Comment: Thank you! The simpler, the better! If you don't know whether a number is positive or negative, you could use the abs() function to make it always positive

array_sum(str_split(abs($number)));

Comment: Funny how this got 70+ votes here and on php manual page it gets downvoted by -40 [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php#121020)

Comment: It´s not only shorter than any loop, but also faster: PHP has no integer division, so a looping solution has to cast the remaining number from float to int in every iteration.

Answer (score 13):

Artefactos method is obviously unbeatable, but here an version how one could do it "manually":

```
$number = 1234567890;
$sum = 0;
do {
    $sum += $number % 10;
}
while ($number = (int) ($number / 10));
```

This is actually faster than Artefactos method (at least for `1234567890`), because it saves two function calls.

Comment: what if $number = "12345678901234567890";?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam what about it?

Comment: [A duplicate question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27210718/2943403) because this answer is unexplained.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, not so fast, not single line simple

```
<?php

    $n = 123;
    $nstr = $n . "";

    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($nstr); ++$i)
    {
        $sum += $nstr[$i];
    }
    echo $sum;

?>
```

It also assumes the number is positive.

Comment: @Frank Farmer Efficiency wouldn't be calculating the string length on each iteration :P

Comment: True, but that's still probably better than building a whole array via str_split.

Answer (score 3):

```
function addDigits($num) {

    if ($num % 9 == 0 && $num > 0) {
        return 9;
    } else {
          return $num % 9;
        }
    }
```

only O(n)

at LeetCode submit result：
Runtime: 4 ms, faster than 92.86% of PHP online submissions for Add Digits.
Memory Usage: 14.3 MB, less than 100.00% of PHP online submissions for Add Digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
// PHP program to calculate the sum of digits 
function sum($num) { 
    $sum = 0; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($num); $i++){ 
        $sum += $num[$i]; 
    } 
    return $sum; 
} 

// Driver Code 
$num = "925"; 
echo sum($num); 
?>
```

Result will be 9+2+5 = 16

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php

$num = 525;
$sum = 0;

while ($num > 0)
{
    $sum= $sum + ($num % 10);
    $num= $num / 10;
}
echo "Summation=" . $sum;

?>
```

Comment: infinite loop: $num will become a quote after the first digit that is not `0`. Try `while ($num|0)`. And btw: `for(;$num|0;$num/=10)$sum+=$num%10;`

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If interested with regex:

```
array_sum(preg_split("//", $number));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
echo"----Sum of digit using php----";
echo"<br/ >";
$num=98765;
$sum=0;
$rem=0;
for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++)
{
$rem=$num%10;
$sum=$sum+$rem;
$num=$num/10;
}
echo "The sum of digit 98765 is ".$sum;
?>
-----------------Output-------------
----Sum of digit using php----
The sum of digit 98765 is 35
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// math before code 

// base of digit sums is 9 

// the product of all numbers multiplied by 9 equals 9 as digit sum

$nr = 58821.5712; // any number

// Initiallization 

$d = array();

$d = explode(".",$nr); // cut decimal digits

$fl = strlen($d[1]); // count decimal digits

$pow = pow(10 ,$fl); // power up for integer

$nr = $nr * $pow; // make float become integer

// The Code

$ds = $nr % 9; // modulo of 9 

if($ds == 0) $ds=9; // cancel out zeros

echo $ds;
```

Comment: maximum 7 float digits

Answer (score -1):

Assume you want to find the sum of the digits of a number say 2395 the simplest solution would be to first split the digits and find out the sum then concatenate all the numbers into one  single number.

```
<?php
    $number=2;
    $number1=3;
    $number2=9;
    $number3=5;
    $combine=$number.$number1.$number2.$number3;
    $sum=$number+$number1+$number2+$number3;
    echo "The sum of $combine is $sum";
     ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of getting sum of digit however this is a slowest route.

```
$n=123;
while(($n=$n-9)>9);
echo "n: $n";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>detail</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$n = 123;
$sum=0; $n1=0;

  for ($i =0; $i<=strlen($n);$i++)
 {

  $n1=$n%10;

   $sum += $n1;
   $n=$n/10;
  }
 echo $sum;

 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the code.. Please try this

```
   <?php 
    $d=0;
   $num=12345;

   $temp=$num;

   $sum=0;

   while($temp>1)

     {
      $temp=$temp/10;

        $d++;
         }

     echo "Digits Are : $d </br>";

      for (;$num>1;)

             {
              $d=$num%10;

             $num=$num/10;

             $sum=$sum+$d;

             }

           echo "Sum of Digits is : $sum";

   ?>
```