# how to do a sum on a string in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, sum

i have a simple question:

i have this var: `$v = "24000,1500,1500,1500,1500,1500,";`

i would like to add those numbers together.

i've tried to `str_replace` the `,` with `+` and so a `eval()`, but that didn't worked.

i also tried `str_split()` but it doesn't know to split on the `,`.

maybe if somehow convert it to an array and do a `array_sum`...

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: [Without delimiting characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232511/get-the-sum-of-all-digits-in-a-numeric-string)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$sum = array_sum( explode( ',', $v ) );
```

What this does is split `$v` by the delimiter `,` with [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) and sum the resulting array of parts with [`array_sum()`](http://www.php.net/array_sum).

Comment: thanks. it works just fine. and someone you would think to try that, but i just went to the complicated stuff. :)

Comment: hi i want to sum up this value how can I do?
$dt = '100+100+200+500';

echo $dt

i want to get 900 as result

Answer (score 4):

```
$v = "24000,1500,1500,1500,1500,1500,";
$result = 0;
foreach(explode(',',$v) as $val)
     $result +=intval($val);

echo $result;///31500
```

Answer (score 1):

Use str_getcsv to obtain an array of the values. Then loop through the array to sum those values.

Answer (score 1):

The `explode` function works best in your situation. What `explode` does is that it splits the string based on the parameter that you specify it. You can think of it as slicing the string based on the parameter and putting it in an array.

Once done, you have a bunch of numbers in the array. Just do a sum. If you want to ensure that all are numbers, you can use is_numeric() to ensure. (:

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_sum()
{
    global $v;
    $temp=0;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($v);$i++)
    {
        $temp+=intval($v[$i]);
    }
    echo $temp;
}

echo get_sum();
```

Comment: Can I suggest explaining the working parts of this answer so the person asking the question understands how it works/what it is. And how to use it.