# PHP for loop being way too slow with big inputs ( Digit Sum loop )

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Dear all I ask for your advice.

I have the following code/ **for** loop in **PHP**

```
$number= 123
$counter = 0;
$digitsum = 6 /* This is calculated by another function */

for($i=1;$i<=$number-1;$i++) {
if(array_sum(preg_split('//',$i)) == $digitsum){
  $counter++;
       }    
}

echo $counter;
```

So basicly my loop counts how many numbers below the given number have the same Digit Sum and then displays how many there are. Even though it works perfectly with as long as 5 digit numbers and calcualtes the loops number within 1 second, I need it to work with 18 digit numbers and complete the counting within 1 second.

Is this even possible to achieve? Or should I go for some other solution ?

Comment: `preg_` is quite slow. You might get better results using `explode()` or by converting the number to a string and then loop over the characters in the string.

Comment: @ThomWiggers is on the right path. Try working with `str_split((string)$i);`

Comment: 18 digits? it will cost a long time in `for loop` even doing nothing in your loop......

Comment: str_split was as slow, @Fu XU what would you suggest to use then ?

Comment: that is a mathematical question....what's the value range of `$digitsum`  ?

Comment: and the digit is fixed at 18?

Comment: nope, maximum lenght of the number can be up to 18 chars

Comment: I think you're running into the limitations of available processing power. Maybe if you tell us the actual use-case, we can come up with a different solution.

Comment: What if I would split the loop in to multiple loops, so they all run simultaneously if the , for instance, number is greater then 999 999 ?
And for every 6 digit figure it would run it's own loop and count the occurances and then sum them in the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very fast solution.  It still won't handle 18 digits in 1 second, but it can do the example in the answer by @Edakos (6, 12345) in only 2 ms.

```
function count_numbers_with_digit_sum( $sum, $max ) {
    if($sum < 0 || $max <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    $count = 0;
    $greatest_piece = (int) str_pad(1, strlen($max.""), "0");
    $first_digit = (int) substr($max, 0, 1);

    if( $max <= 9 && $sum <= 9 ) {
        $count++;
    }
    else {
        $count_to = max(1, ($sum > $first_digit) ? $first_digit : $sum );
        for( $i = 0; $i < $count_to; $i++ ) {
            $count += count_numbers_with_digit_sum( $sum - $i, $greatest_piece - 1 );
        }
        $count += count_numbers_with_digit_sum( $sum - $count_to, $max % $greatest_piece );
    }
    return $count;
}

$start = microtime(true);
echo count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 6, 12345);
echo "<br/>";
echo (int)((microtime(true) - $start)*1000) )." ms";
```

Some sample runs:

```
count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 9,  100    ) = 10      0 ms
count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 6,  123    ) = 10      0 ms
count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 6,  12345  ) = 130     2 ms
count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 23, 12345  ) = 530     40 ms
count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 34, 582973 ) = 13923   2287 ms
count_numbers_with_digit_sum( 9,  984930 ) = 2001    39 ms
```

Here's how it works.  Let's call `S(x,y)` the number of distinct, positive integers less than or equal to `y` that have the sum of their digits equal to `x`.  For example, `S(3,25) = 3` (3, 12, 21).  We can do the following logic.  For simplicity, let's look only at x=6 and y=123, like in your original example.  `S` will be the number of integers where we don't "use" the first (hundreds) digit, plus the number of integers where we do.  The hundreds digit in this scenario has a maximum value of 1, so...

```
S(6,123) = S(6,99) + S(5,23)
```

Looking at the tens digit, we can use any value from 0 to 6, so:

```
S(6,99) =   S(6,9) // single digits
          + S(5,9) // 10-19
          + S(4,9) // 20-29
          + S(3,9) // 30-39
          + S(2,9) // 40-49
          + S(1,9) // 50-59
          + S(0,9) // 60
```

This lends itself very well to recursion.  For a given `y`, we look at the scenarios where all the leftmost digits are 0 (i.e., not used), like S(x,9), S(x,99), S(x,999), etc., and then we look at the "maxed-out" leftmost digit.  For example,

```
S(34, 12345) = S(34, 9999) + S(34, 999) + S(34, 99) + S(34, 9) + S(33, 2345)
             = 10          + 0          + 0         + 0        + S(33, 2345)
             = 10 + S(33, 999) + S(33, 99) + S(33, 9) + S(31, 345)
             = 10 + 0          + 0         + 0        + S(31, 345)
             = 10 + S(31, 99) + S(31, 9) + S(31, 45)
             = 10 + 0         + 0        + 0
             = 10
```

The function above implements this recursion.  You can easily adapt this function to work with large "numbers" as string values:

```
function count_numbers_with_digit_sum_string( $sum, $max ) {
    return count_numbers_with_digit_sum_string_inner( $sum."", $max."" );
}

function count_numbers_with_digit_sum_string_inner( $sum, $max ) {
    if($sum < 0 || $max <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    $count = 0;
    $strlenmax = strlen($max);
    $strlensum = strlen($sum);
    $nines_less_than_max = (int) str_pad("", $strlenmax-1, "9");
    $first_digit = (int) substr($max, 0, 1);
    $last_two_digits_sum = (int) substr($sum, -2);

    if( $strlenmax <= 1 && $strlensum <= 1 ) {
        $count++;
    }
    else {
        $count_to = max( 1, ($strlensum > 1 || $sum > $first_digit) ? $first_digit : ( (int) $sum ) );
        for( $i = 0; $i < $count_to; $i++ ) {
            $count += count_numbers_with_digit_sum_string_inner( substr($sum, 0, -2) .($last_two_digits_sum - $i), $nines_less_than_max );
        }
        $count += count_numbers_with_digit_sum_string_inner( substr($sum, 0, -2) .($last_two_digits_sum - $count_to), substr($max, 1));
    }
    return $count;
}
$start = microtime(true);
echo count_numbers_with_digit_sum_string( 34, 12345);
echo "<br>".( (int)((microtime(true) - $start)*1000) )." ms";
```

This version takes about twice as long as the purely numeric version above.

You could speed this up tremendously by precalculating and caching values.  As you can see above, there are lots of terms like `S(x, 999)`, `S(x,9999)`, etc.  There are only 10 values of x (0..9) that "work" where y = 9, 19 values (0..18) that work for y = 99, 28 (0..27) for y = 999, etc.  If you wanted to cache, say, 1,558 values (all combinations of S(x,y) for y in 9, 99, 999, up to 999,999,999,999,999,999), you could cut out a tremendous amount of the recursion and save a huge amount of time.  With a big enough cache, I am confident you can get the times for 18-digit numbers down to one second.  This would be easy to do, by building up to it (cache the 9 values, then 99, then 999, etc.).  If I have time later, I will post a proof of concept.

Hope that helps!

(Edited to clarify caching calculation, fix calculation error in $count_to)

Comment: This is by far the most detailed and best answer and gave some good insight to the problem, given code isn't as fast but I'll try to achieve it with cache and predetermined calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster because it doesn't use regex:

```
<?php

$number = 123;
$counter = 0;
$digitsum = 6; /* This is calculated by another function */

for($i=1;$i<=$number-1;$i++) {
    if(array_sum(str_split($i)) == $digitsum) {
        $counter++; 
    }
}

echo $counter;
```

Comment: Nope, this would just output `0`.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. Now it works (at least if the expected output is 9 :) )

Comment: But still quite slow for big numbers :(

Comment: I changed it. Now it's faster

Comment: Sadly it's not even close :( I'm not sure if its even possible to calculate the outcome from a 999 999 999 999 999 999 within 1 second( for example ) :S

Comment: In speed? You can try a string as proposed in the comments, but I doubt it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try option C from the following:

**Option A:** (your attempt)

```
$number   = 12345;
$counter  = 0;
$digitsum = 6; 

$start = microtime();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $number - 1; $i++) {
    if (array_sum(preg_split('//', $i)) == $digitsum) {
        $counter++; 
    }
}

echo (int)((microtime() - $start)*1000); // ~ 42 miliseconds at writecodeonline.com
```

**Option B:** (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232531/2905135))

```
$start = microtime();

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < $number) {
    if (array_sum(str_split($i)) == $digitsum) {
        $counter++; 
    }
}

echo (int)((microtime() - $start)*1000); // ~ 19 miliseconds at writecodeonline.com
```

**Option C:** (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232634/2905135))

```
$start = microtime();

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < $number) {
    $sum = 0;
    $n = $i;
    do {
        $sum += $n % 10;
    } while ($sum <= $digitsum and $n = (int) $n / 10);

    if ($sum == $digitsum) {
        $counter++; 
    }
} 
echo (int)((microtime() - $start)*1000); // ~ 5 miliseconds at writecodeonline.com
```

Comment: option C is ( like my posted code ) able to handle up to 6 digits within 1 sec , 7 digits within 3-4 secs and from 8th digit times out.
So it just times out :( Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want

```
function foo($digits, $digitsum) {
    $sum = 0;
    if(!empty($digits)) {
        if($digitsum > 1) {
            $current = array_shift($digits);
            if(count($digits) > 0) {
                if($digitsum >= $current) {
                    $sum += foo($digits, $digitsum - $current);
                    for($i = 0; $i < $current; $i++) {
                        $sum += foo(array_fill(0, count($digits), 9), $digitsum - $i);
                    }
                } else {
                    for($i = 0; $i <= $digitsum; $i++) {
                        $sum += foo(array_fill(0, count($digits), 9), $digitsum - $i);
                    }
                }
            } elseif($current >= $digitsum) {
                $sum += 1;
            }
        } elseif($digitsum == 1) {
            $sum += count($digits);
        } else {
            $sum += 1;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
$number   = 123;
$digitsum = 6;

$digit = strlen($number);
$digits = str_split($number);
$counter = foo($digits, $digitsum);
var_dump($counter);
```

Comment: This is by far the fastest solution so far, however it can handle only up to 10 digits , and that with 20 second. 9 digits work within 1 second. So i think the only way to go is to cache some values before and then calculate it..

Comment: i didn't solve the mathematical problem yet, i believe it will faster when i solve that problem :)