# MySQL SUM number within string

Tags: mysql

I have a `movies` table

```
SELECT * FROM movies

+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|            MovieTitle             |                         Awards                          |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Rocky 20                          | Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 37 wins & 46 nominations |
| Die Hard 51                       | Won 1 Oscar. Another 5 wins & 19 nominations.           |
| Killer tomatoes                   | 9 nominations.                                          |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to be able to `SUM` all the numbers of award/nominations in  `Awards` such as to have something like this:

```
    +-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
    |            MovieTitle             |                         Awards                          | Total |
    +-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
    | Rocky 20                          | Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 37 wins & 46 nominations |    84 |
    | Die Hard 51                       | Won 1 Oscar. Another 5 wins & 19 nominations.           |    25 |
    | Killer tomatoes                   | 9 nominations.                                          |     9 |
    +-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Any suggestions on how I could achieve that with only MySQL?

Comment: You should really store the awards information in a different format.  What you want to do is not what relational databases are designed to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree. I got the data in this format so now I have to deal with those.

Comment: Can't you change of format ? Using a PHP script to process this and insert the data in the new format would not that complicated.

Comment: @Loufylouf, yes I might end up just doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232511/get-the-sum-of-digits-in-php I was wondering if there was a way to do that in MySQL

Comment: I don't think so, string processing isn't really what databases are for. For example, the way I see it, you would not a function to split the string into an array, filter this array to remove not numbers, then do the sum of numbers contained in this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strings are all looking for the number before "nominations", "wins" and "Oscars".  This simplifies the problem.

You can get the value that you want using string manipulation.  Here is one solution:

```
select ((case when awards like '% nominations%'
              then substring_index(substring_index(awards, ' nominations', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
              else 0
         end) +
        (case when awards like '% wins%'
              then substring_index(substring_index(awards, ' wins', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
              else 0
         end) +
        (case when awards like '% Oscar%'
              then substring_index(substring_index(awards, ' Oscar', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
              else 0
         end)
        ) as TotalMentions
```

I can appreciate having to deal with poorly formed data in a relational database.  In this case, the strings are pretty well formed, so the solution is not that unreasonable.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM OrderDetails;
```

I hope this helps!