# How to calculate checksum on PHP having PERL pattern

Tags: php, perl

I have the following code on PERL:

```
$Mid = 123;
$csum=0;
$csum+=$_ foreach split //,$Mid;
$csum%=10;
```

It calculates `$csum` based on `$Mid` which is a number

How to do the same on PHP?

Comment: What have you tried? "php sum digits in number" yields a lot of results on google/stackoverflow ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232511/get-the-sum-of-digits-in-php) for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
$mid = 123;
$csum = 0;

foreach(str_split($mid) as $m){ // Loop $mid by character
  $csum+= $m;                   // Add current $character ($m) to our $csum
}

$csum = $csum % 10;             // Modulo by 10
echo $csum; // 6
```

[Working PHP](https://3v4l.org/d4kUT), and to compare, the [working Perl](https://ideone.com/TBjZkM) version

Comment: [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) | [`%=`](http://php.net/language.operators.assignment)